# how to extract the selection expressions from the select clause to an array?

Tags: php

Having selection queries like the following. Where each one is an example

```
SELECT column FROM table...
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table...
SELECT column1 AS column_1, column2 AS column_2 FROM table...
SELECT column1 column_1, column2 AS column_2 FROM table...
```

I would like to obtain in an array the selection expressions, so that the results of each of these queries would be the following.

```
['column']
['column1', 'column2']
['column_1', 'column_2']
['column_1', 'column_2']
```

I show different ways of writing the selection expressions, as they can be written in one of these ways.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do what you want. Note that it assumes the formats you have shown above are the **only** ones you want to support. The code strips off the `SELECT` and `FROM` from the start and end of the string, and then gets the column names from the different expressions (allowing for optional `AS xxx` clauses).

```
$selects = array('SELECT column FROM table...',
'SELECT column1, column2 FROM table...',
'SELECT column1 AS column_1, column2 AS column_2 FROM table...',
'SELECT Column1 AS Column_1, column2 AS COLUMN2 FROM table...',
'SELECT column1 column_1, column2 AS column_2 FROM table...');
$fields = array();
foreach ($selects as $select) {
    $select = preg_replace(array('/^SELECT\s+/', '/\s+FROM.*$/', '/\s*(\w+\s+(AS\s+)?)?(\w+)\s*/'), array('', '', '$3'), $select);
    $fields[] = explode(',', $select);
}
print_r($fields);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => column
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => column1
            [1] => column2
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => column_1
            [1] => column_2
        )    
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Column_1
            [1] => COLUMN2
        )    
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => column_1
            [1] => column_2
        )    
)
```

[Demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/UHEUE96076)

Comment: Thanks for answering, It works just as I require. Could you update to support alias_name in lowercase and uppercase

Comment: It should work fine with uppercase alias names, the `\w` will match `A-Z` as well as `a-z`

Comment: I've made an edit with some mixes case examples, also a link to a demo on rextester. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help